# Specify env option for ES7

Tags: javascript, eslint

For using ES6 in the environment, I have to specify the `.eslintrc` file as:

```
"env": {
    "node": false,
    "browser": true,
    "amd": true,
    "mocha": true,
    "jasmine": false,
    "es6": true
}
```

But what when I want to use ES7, can I just:

```
"env": {
    "node": false,
    "browser": true,
    "amd": true,
    "mocha": true,
    "jasmine": false,
    "es7": true
}
```

?

For information, I looked at https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring but did not get the answer.

**Update**

My current file eslint file looks as following:

```
{
    "globals": {
        "com": true,
        "oData": false,
        "sakp": false,
        "fin": true,
        "cloud": true,
        "bsuite": false,
        "cordova": false,
        "ui": true,
        "webide": false,
        "asyncTest": false,
        "i2d": true,
        "gltrade": false,
        "drilldown": true,
        "opaTest": false,
        "ux": true,
        "test": false,
        "$": false,
        "module": false,
        "ai": false,
        "notEqual": false,
        "notDeepEqual": false,
        "throws": false,
        "ssuite": false,
        "deepEqual": false,
        "s2p": false,
        "Promise": false,
        "ehs": false,
        "sinon": false,
        "stop": false,
        "util": true,
        "slo": false,
        "mdm": false,
        "mytravelandexpense": false,
        "strictEqual": false,
        "cec": false,
        "cus": false,
        "notStrictEqual": false,
        "fscm": false,
        "fm": true,
        "nw": true,
        "shcm": false,
        "fcg": true,
        "URI": false,
        "fs": true,
        "retail": false,
        "d3": false,
        "hcm": false,
        "oil": true,
        "assert": false,
        "hpa": false,
        "ok": false,
        "sap": true,
        "QUnit": false,
        "cross": true,
        "srm": false,
        "equal": false,
        "expect": false,
        "jQuery": false,
        "publicservices": true,
        "uxcc": false,
        "equals": false,
        "tl": false,
        "travel": true
    },
    "env": {
        "node": false,
        "browser": true,
        "amd": true,
        "mocha": true,
        "jasmine": false,
        "es6": true
    }
}
```

Where to specify es7?

Comment: From the link you've shared: `ecmaVersion - set to 3, 5 (default), 6, 7, 8, or 9 to specify the version of ECMAScript syntax you want to use. You can also set to 2015 (same as 6), 2016 (same as 7), 2017 (same as 8), or 2018 (same as 9) to use the year-based naming`

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control which edition of syntax is allowed, you'll want to set the [`ecmaVersion` under `parserOptions`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options):

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": false,
        "browser": true,
        "amd": true,
        "mocha": true,
        "jasmine": false,
        "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2016
    }
}
```

The value can either be the year or edition number of the specification (e.g. ECMAScript `2018` and the `9`th edition have the same effect).